# How to make the command can be disabled on certain servers discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a list with a list of id discord servers that want to disable some of the functions of my bot.
For example: the on_member_join method will not send a message when a person enters the server, and on the other where this function is enabled, it will send that the person has connected to the server. But I don't know how to properly store the id and use it. At the moment there is this:

```
async def serverid(ctx):
  sid = ctx.message.guild.id
  await ctx.send(sid)
```

sid = 705735563696799723 (id server dependent)

that's roughly what I want to get in the end

```
async def test(ctx):
 f = open('/app/commands/servers.txt', 'r')
 servers_sid = f.readlines()
 now_sid = ctx.message.guild.id

 if now_sid == servers_sid: #i know servers_sid = ['id'] or something similar this is what i have a problem with
  await ctx.send('Command disabled')
 else:
  #command execution
```

i know servers_sid = ['id'] or something similar this is what i have a problem with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `splitlines` so that you will not carry the `\n`. I made the check to be `not in` if it is not in the file then it will just end

```py
async def test(ctx):
    with open('/app/commands/servers.txt', 'r') as f:
        servers_sid = f.read().splitlines()

    now_sid = str(ctx.message.guild.id)

    if now_sid not in servers_sid: 
        await ctx.send('Command disabled')
        return
    


    await ctx.send('This is working')
    #command execution
```

I am assuming you txt file is like this.

```
123
456
789
```

Comment: i get the same result in both cases (1 - server is in the list, 2 - server is not in the list)
now code: https://ibb.co/685jbQH ; OUTPUT : command disabled, 705735563696799796 (now_sid), ['705735563696799796'] (servers.txt)

Comment: @THEMakci7m87 please check now, I made `now_sid` as a string